# Decode base64 from “content-disposition: attachment” body part

Tags: email, base64, procmail, mime-mail

I am trying to extract message body using procmail be it in the message or in an attachment, but I got first two characters from below:

```
:0B
* ^()[a-z]+[0-9]+[^\+]
{ msgID = "$MATCH" }
:0B
* ^Content-Disposition: *attachment.*(($)[a-z0-9].*)*($)($)\/[a-z]+[0-9]+
| base64 --decode
{ msgID = "$MATCH" }
```

The decoding of base64 is not working, it's either not matching as whole condition, or assigning `LASTFOLDER=base64 --decode"`

See also [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32292295/extract-text-from-content-disposition-attachment-body-part)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two actions on a single recipe.  Where you have

```
:0B
* ^stuff\/more stuff
{ msgid="$MATCH" }
| base64 --decode
```

the second line is a syntax error.  I'm guessing you mean something like

```
:0B
* ^stuff\/more stuff
{
     msgid="$MATCH"
     :0
     | base64 --decode
}
```

See?  If you need more than one action, add a pair of braces (don't forget the closing braces at the end!) around another group of recipes as the action section.  Maybe see also http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/quickref.html

But in your case, you apparently want to extract the token base64 decoded, so the code you are looking for would be

```
:0B
* ^Content-Disposition: *attachment.*(($)[a-z0-9].*)*($)($)\/[a-z]+[0-9]+
{ msgID=`echo "$MATCH" | base64 --decode` }
```

Notice also that you cannot have a space around the equals sign.  And the regex is incorrect for arbitrary base64; plus and slash are also among the allowed characters, and equals at the end. Change the part after `\/` to `[a-z0-9/+]+=*`

Comment: Now I extracted it, but somehow it's not decode the input which is valid: procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER=base64 --decode"
procmail: Notified comsat: "r@:/var/mail//base64 -d"
procmail: Executing "base64,-d"
 Subject: Fwd: hi
  Folder: base64 --decode                                                        
base64: invalid input

Comment: @tripleeee For base64 I added the following before decode it:
  * ^Content-Transfer-Encoding: .*base64
or ...:*64, there's always no match for it, I check the email, it does have it.

Comment: Works for me: http://pastebin.com/ESHtyxkc ... Maybe update your question with a similar transcript of your attempt. (Don't post as a comment; you can't get decent code formatting in comments, even with `code tags`.)

Comment: See also now http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733374/874188 which prefers `printf` over `echo`.

Comment: procmail: Assigning "LASTFOLDER={msgID=printf %s "$MATCH" | base64 --decode}"
procmail: Opening "{msgID=printf %s "$MATCH" | base64 --decode}"
procmail: Error while writing to "{msgID=printf %s "$MATCH" | base64 --decode}" @tripleee

Comment: You need a space inside the opening brace. (Sorry for the rhyme.)

Comment: I made a space, but it still complains about: procmail: Assigning "msgID=printf %s "$MATCH" | base64 -d" for 
mysql: unknown option '-d' or '--decode' @tripleee

Comment: Looks like you are also lacking the backticks around the command, if I read that correctly.  (Not sure where `for mysql` or the stuff after that comes from.)